# How To Take SQL Server Backup From One Server To Another Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Folks,
I have multiple sql servers so Here i want take backup from server TO server.

> Actually i want to store all backup files at only one server.Not to
>   move manually or Copy/Paste backup files.

Also i search out it on google on my way but didn't get exact idead to how to perform. also not know if any security issues are affected.

FYI..SQL Server Management Studio is installed at all servers.

Comment: Have you thought about creating the backup in the shared folder / network folder and restoring from that folder? Are all the servers in the same network?

Comment: @KhathiravanRaj . Want to take backup from another server's SSMS.All servers are in same network.

Comment: you might want to create backup using SQL's create backup command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and drop the file into common network share, then use the restore backup SQL command to restore from the network location.

Comment: Yes, But i don't know SQL's create command or any other way that can take backup of Database that is on another Server.

Comment: I think you are asking if you can log onto a random server, then backup a SQL Server database that lives on a different server?  If this is the case then why would you want to do this?  One example of how this might work, is you could have a simple batch application that runs on a server, logs on to a number of other servers, runs backups remotely, then logs off, then copies all said backups to a network location.  There are certainly security issues with doing this, as that one user will have to be granted considerable rights on each SQL Server instance to do this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the backups on your central server?

Comment: @RichardHansell you are right..!! But what i do right now is, i have multiple servers so for history backups i have to take backup through SSMS and Move that big size file via fileZilla.but i want take backup from backup server to all Production server. so i come out the headache of Moving those files into backup servers.

Comment: Use a fully-qualified UNC path as the backup target. Like `backup database foo to disk = '\\otherServer\backups\foo.bak';`